# How to run AngularJS unit tests against the minified app with Webpack and Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, webpack-2, karma-webpack

I'm working on an AngularJS application. We have a large existing codebase which we are moving to Webpack 2 in preparation for ng-upgrade. However we can't figure out how to run our Jasmine unit tests against the minified app.

We have modeled our application after [this](https://github.com/preboot/angularjs-webpack) preboot repository.

We uglify the app using this in `webpack.config.js`:

```
config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: false})
);
```

`karma.conf.js` basically looks like this:

```
module.exports = function karmaConfig (config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: ['src/tests.webpack.js'],
    preprocessors: {
       'src/tests.webpack.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },
    webpack: require('./webpack.config'),
    ...
  });
};
```

`src/tests.webpack.js` looks like this:

```
import 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks/angular-mocks';

const context = require.context('..', true, /\.spec.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

Each `.spec.js` file uses `import` to load the actual Angular application, then does some injection like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
    ...
}));
```

This is where we have a problem. Our unit tests are being minified. `$rootScope` is minified to `e`, which the injector fails to find. We want to minify only the app, not test files. How can we do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem here...`However we can't figure out how to run our Jasmine unit tests against the minified app` Why are you testing against a minified app? `Our unit tests are being minified. $rootScope is minified to e, which the injector fails to find.` Are you using proper dependency injection to support minification?  `We want to minify only the app, not test files. How can we do this?` Modify the `UglifyJsPlugin` settings to exclude test files.

Comment: @BenBeck Thanks for the help. `UglifyJsPlugin` only supports excluding chunks, not source files. We can't figure out how to get Karma to work with multiple chunks.

We are testing against a minified app because we want to check for missing strict injections, corrupt build, etc. We run minified on prod, so we want tests to pass minified.

We could use strict dependency injection in `angular.mock.inject()` but we'd rather avoid minifying unit tests at all.

Comment: According to the docs, UglifyJsPlugin does indeed support an `exclude`  option for `Files to exclude from testing`. Maybe you can use that?  If not, can you reduce your `include` test? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

Comment: @olore The documentation is misleading. It operates on chunks, not files. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1079. I have tried separating our tests out into chunks using `CommonsChunkPlugin`, but I can't figure out how to get Karma to load multiple chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have this code in your tests:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
    ...
}));
```

minification changes the variable names so they might look something like:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($a){
    ...
}));
```

The problem is that angular inspects the angular parameters at runtime, and has no idea what `a` is!!

The solution:

```
beforeEach(inject(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    ...
}]));
```

This way even if the parameter names are mangled, the string `$rootScope` gives angular a hint what each parameter refers to